# mySQL Update tuple based on foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Imagine having 2 tables - Vehicles & Manufacturers.

Vehicles (Id[PK], Manufacturer_Id[FK], Name, Price, Discount)

Manufacturers (Id[PK], Name)

If I want to update all Vehicles whose Manufacturer Name is 'BMW'.

My clunky way...

```
"SELECT Id FROM Manufacturers WHERE Name = 'BMW'";
```

once I have the Manufacturer Id I can run the update query.

```
UPDATE Vehicles SET Discount='0.1' WHERE Manufacturer_Id='$manuId'
```

What I am looking for is a more elegant solution, whereby I can somehow reference 'BMW' within the update statement, and doing away with the select query.

e.g. I want to do something like this... If at all possible:

```
UPDATE Vehicles SET Discount='0.1' WHERE Vehicles.Manufacturer_Id = Manufacturer.Id AND Manufacturer.Name = 'BMW'
```

Comment: maybe something like doing and `update` using `where in`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474879/mysql-update-where-in-for-each-listed-value-separately

Comment: 10% off beemers? where do I sign up? Or is that a 1 penny discount? Where do I remove my name from the list?

Comment: LOL!!! Well it was just an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Vehicles SET Discount='0.1' WHERE Manufacturer_Id IN 
(SELECT id FROM Manufacturers WHERE Name = 'BMW');
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this query should work:

```
UPDATE Vehicles SET Discount='0.1' WHERE Manufacturer_Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Manufacturers WHERE Name = 'BMW'")
```

Comment: Sorry mate, Matt S got there 2 mins before you. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer is sub-select, but in general sub-selects are not good for performance.  Suppose OK in this case.  If needing to use Manufacturers key pairs (id-name) frequently, populating selects, getting id from name as you show, etc.  It might make sense to use an Identity Map pattern (assuming some semblance of OOP) and additionally using something like memcache for you caching strategy to cut down even more on trips to the database.

Comment: This is over-engineering and not a good solution for any average size database with proper indexes.

Comment: Didn't see a mention to size.  If OP is trying to prevent the superfluous 'look up' selects I think my answer is also valid.  I don't personally equate sub-selects with elegance.